# Laravel translatable fallback issue when writing label in other language than default one

Tags: laravel, translation

In Laravel 8, with astrotomic translatable, i have a fallback for french language.

For new labels, if i'm in french, and then set the environnement to english, i have the default label displayed.
But if the environment is set to english, the label in database is set to english, and not duplicate in french. So when returning in a french environment i have no label displayed because the fallback only check the french value label.

In the Model I have a :

```
public $translatedAttributes = ['label']
```

It works to display default language when nothing is set in another language.
But i have no default label, if the value is set from a different language.

Update:

When i access my application, the default language is 'fr',
I have a

```
session(['locale' => 'fr'])
```

In this situation, no problem, my label is stored in the model_translations table with the attribute 'fr'. If i change the language,

```
session(['local' => 'en'])
```

I have the default display of the label from model_translations table, the one with the 'fr' attribute. It's OK.

But if i access my app, and set the language to another one

```
session(['locale' => 'en'])
```

when i store a label, it's stored in model_translations table with the attribute 'en', so when i get back in 'fr', i got no label at all.

So in documentation
https://docs.astrotomic.info/laravel-translatable/package/fallback-locale
It's said to set the fallback_locale to null, to get the first in order of the configuration. But i can't succeed to do so

Comment: Can you give some examples, its not very clear when the label doesn't work.

Comment: Off course, i'll try to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent my problem, i had to test if i had en existing label in the default language. If not, it duplicate the tranlasted label in both current language and default language.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).